# polyhornerscheme error

Tags: polynom

I am using the package polynom.
I want to make next Horner’s scheme `$\dfrac{x^2+mx+1}{x+2}$` using next command:

`\polyhornerscheme[x=-2]{x^2+mx+1}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polynom} % Polynomial division

\begin{document}
    \polyhornerscheme[x=-2]{x^2+mx+1}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

But there is an error in the result (see the remainder). I should obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r|rrr}
             & 1 & $m$  & 1\\
        $-2$ &   & $-2$ & $-2m+4$\\ \hline
             & 1 & $m-2$& $-2m+5$
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks.